# Forward testing in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab. I have been going through a lot of the tutorials and the documentation. A lot of people here have helped.(looking at the code helps a lot.

Now I want to go ahead and set-up a test for the data that I have loaded into matlab, the method I am following:

Load data from excel sheet using the import tool(I have generated the script for this).

This loads the data into 3 different symbols in the workspace: x,y,APC

After this I set a condition using:

```
BUYx = x(find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first'))  
SELLy = y(find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first'))
BUYy = y(find(APC > 0.44,1,'first'))
SELLx = x(find(APC > 0.44,1,'first'))
```

This gets me value in suppose the top set i.e. BUYx and SELLy.

Suppose BUYx and SELLy was the 100th entry/element in x and y respectively. Now I want BUYx and SELLy to generate a Profit/Loss file where it goes through the next element in x and y i.e. as per the 101, 102...so on element in x and y till a new condition is met(say APC >-1.5).

How would I go about this? I have tried a lot of things but I just can't figure out which functions would be able correct to get this data.

Thanks in advance.

@Fletch The code I am using now, thanks to your guidance:

```
EUBuyIndexStart = find(APC < -2.9079, 1,'first');
EUBuyIndexStop = find(APC(EUBuyIndexStart:end) > -2.5000,1,'first');
BUYEU = EU(EUBuyIndexStart); 
EURange = EU(EUBuyIndexStart:EUBuyIndexStop);
```

Still doesn't work though, it just won't start using the range i.e.EUBuyIndexStart:end. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain I can solve your problem, generally. For a specific answer, I'm going to need a bit more detail. I can't seem to figure out exactly what you're asking, so I'm going to do my best.

The general answer is: find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first') returns an index value, which you are then using to index into x in the line:

`BUYx = x(find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first'))`

What find() really gives you is the index (which is like an address) for the first value in the vector that meet the criteria you specify. So, to get all of the values between two conditions (which is what I think you're asking for) you can do this:

```
xBuyIndexStart = find(APC < -2.9079, 1,'first');  % This is your condition.
xBuyIndexStop  = find(APC < -5.6000, 1,'first');  % I just made this condition up.
BUYx = x(xBuyIndexStart);                         % This is the same as your old BUYx value I just included it for your understanding.
xRange = x(xBuyIndexStart:xBuyIndexStop)          % this is a vector containing all x-values between your start and stop contrition.
```

Rinse, lather, repeat for y, and you'll have two vectors containing all of the values between the two conditions you specify. Let me know if I missed the point of your question, and I'll try again. Good luck!

Comment: thanks. I am trying this out now. I will update the question with results and clarification/details.

Comment: Hmmm...weird I am getting the xBuyIndexStart as 31206 and xBuyIndexStop as 713. I assume these are references to the location of the data. Strange because I expected these to be opposite I mean in excel the 'location' would be the other way around. After that, xRange is Empty matrix. Fletch anyway we can talk or PM?

Comment: Interesting, did you use -5.6000? I just made that number up, so there's no guarantee it would work. You'll need to use a real number from your actual data set to test this code. Otherwise, you're right, it should be the other way around.

Comment: Hmmm...I changed it to > -1.5. Now getting a indexstop = 1 indexstart=31206. It would be great if we can use a messenger or something. Is it frowned upon to give email address here?

Comment: Yeah, I think that makes sense. If you made it greater than -1.5, and the first element was greater than -1.5, it should return 1.

Comment: the first element is greater than -1.5, I needed the function to pick the next value which would be above -1.5 i.e. after the -2.6 any value which occurs greater than -1.5.

Comment: Ahhh. I know how to do that. What you need to do is run the second find() search on only the portion of the array which occurs AFTER the index returned from the first find() search. It looks like this: 
`xBuyIndexStop  = find(APC(xBuyIndexStart:end) > -1.5000, 1,'first');`

Comment: Notice the keyword `end` It's a special symbol in MATLAB that, when used as an index, returns the highest index in that array. So, `APC(xBuyIndexStart:end)` returns only the part of APC between xBuyIndexStart and the end of APC. You're then searching only that part of APC with the secon find() search.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the new code, understood the concept. However it is still returning me an index value above the xBuyIndexStart. I checked with the data and found where the Index location should be and can't get it to work. I am giving it a few more tries.

Comment: Hmmm...just won't take the correct range i.e. wont search only between xBuyIndexStart:end. :(

Comment: I think I may see the problem. Maybe. I think the line find(APC(EUBuyIndexStart:end) > -2.5000,1,'first'); is actually returning the index of the (EUBuyIndexStart:end) subset of APC. So if it returns 5 it means the 5th element of APC(EUBuyIndexStart:end), not the fifth element of APC(0:end). That means that EURange should equal EU(EUBuyIndexStart: **EUBuyIndexStart +** EUBuyIndexStop); Try that.